# Can't boot Ubuntu 22.04 (server) without connected HDMI?

Tags: server, 22.04, display, hdmi

I have a chatreey mini PC that I installed Ubuntu 22.04 lts server onto. This was done with the install USB drive using an HDMI monitor and USB keyboard. I got everything updated/upgraded and setup ssh and have samba running - all was well.

Then I turned off, removed the HDMI monitor and it refuses to boot all the way. When I reconnect and get booted again, then unplug the HDMI monitor while it is running, it freezes. I can tell because I have an ssh shell running remotely, which freezes. Reconnecting the HDMI again unfreezes the ssh session and the monitor + keyboard continue working as expected. I cannot boot without a connected HDMI now.

What is happening? What subsystem notices the removal of an HDMI connector? I can find my way around linux but am not a sysadmin so any hint or what log to look in would be appreciated -- BTW no obvious error in syslogs.